# Cannot redirect command output to a file (for postfix status)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to run the following command:

```
postfix status > tmp
```

however the resulting file never has any content written, and instead the output is still sent to the terminal.

I have tried adding  the following into the mix, and even piping to echo before redirecting the output, but nothing seems ot have any effect

```
postfix status 2>&1 > tmp
```

Other commands work no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to another SO user, who deleted their answer, so now I can't thank, I was put on the right track. I found the answer here:

http://irbs.net/internet/postfix/0211/2756.html

So for those who want to be able to catch the response of the posfix, I used the following method.

**Create a script** which causes the output to go to where you wish. I did that like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat <<EOF | expect 2>&1 
set timeout -1 
spawn postfix status
expect eof 
EOF
```

Then i ran the script (say script.sh) and could pipe/redirect from there. i.e. script.sh > file.txt

I needed this for PHP so I could use exec and actually get a response.

Answer (score 5):

```
script -c 'postfix status' -q tmp
```

Comment: Could you expand a little bit on that ? As it stands, it would be a good comment to golimar's answer, but he's the one explaining it.

Comment: script -c 'logrotate -d -f /etc/logrotate.conf' -q /tmp/log.txt

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it writes to the terminal instead to stdout. I don't understand piping to 'echo', did you mean piping to 'cat'?

I think you can always use the 'script' command, that logs everything that you see on the terminal. You would run 'script', then your command, then exit.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled into a solution that's a bit cleaner than using expect.  If you use SSH and SSH keys, you can allocate a pseudo-tty and get the output as you normally would.

```
PFS=$(ssh -tt localhost "postfix status")
```

Puts the output into $PFS in bash.

This would also work in PHP, in whatever way you'd expect to get STDOUT output from any of the program execution functions.  Once I put it in a PHP script, I had to double-up the -t to -tt in order to force allocation of a terminal.